# How to keep fruits and other objects in a vertical position?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, still-life

I noticed that the photos with fruits and vegetables look much better if you put them in a vertical position (or very close to vertical position) and you shoot the photo from a horizontal position. Example: [Pera limonera](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Pera_limonera_2017_A1.jpg/600px-Pera_limonera_2017_A1.jpg)

And, they look not really good when they are shoot from above. Also it's not very convenient to try to shoot from above in a light box. Example: [Conference pears](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2_x_Curved_conference_pear_2017_A.jpg) - [Mutant persimmon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Mutant_persimmon_2017_A4.jpg/677px-Mutant_persimmon_2017_A4.jpg) - [Conference pear](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Curved_conference_pear_2017_A.jpg/656px-Curved_conference_pear_2017_A.jpg)

Also, it's better if they touch the ground, instead of putting them on top of some small paper supports (for keeping them in a close to vertical position). They look artificial this way. Example: [Conference pears](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/2_x_Conference_pear_2017_C.jpg/748px-2_x_Conference_pear_2017_C.jpg) - I made rings from paper and from tin foil to convince the fruits to stay close to a vertical position.

I am using coins and a small locker behind the fruits most of the time, because they are heavy so they will not be moved by the fruit. I can shape tin foil into all kind of shapes but it only works for light objects. Plasticine is heavier but it's not good because it can stain the paper background.

I guess I'm not the only one using supports behind the objects in order to keep them in a vertical position. Is there a generic name for such objects/tools?

What are the options for doing this?

A malleable and heavy material? Better if it doesn't leave stains, but if it does, then I can use it on a wooden/plastic background.

Comment: Modelling clay? Pile of sand with a cloth over it? Find fruit that have a reasonably flat bottom? All kinds of options. Nothing wrong with coins or folded paper either, as long as you get the shot you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Model Magic](http://www.crayola.com/things-to-do/how-to-landing/model-magic/) is what we use for seashells. It should easily work for fruits which already have  lower center of gravity usually. Its a very maleable but dries into something like a dense sponge and keeps its shape perfectly one dry. We shape it into all sorts of supporting shapes.

Now, if you are willing to damage for fruits in the name of photography, I would add a toothpick with one end in the fruit and the other in the modeling magic for greater stability and precision.

Comment: "Supporting shape" is the usual term for these items?

Comment: Actually, the term is usually just *support*.